# User is connecting to socket.io server twice

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log(`User Connected: ${socket.id}`);

    //joining Room
    socket.join(selectedOption);
    socket.broadcast.emit("userConn", `${username} joined ${selectedOption}`);

    socket.on('emitMessage', (data) => {
      if(data.room == selectedOption){
        socket.broadcast.to(selectedOption).emit('message', {username: data.username , message: data.message});
      }
    });
});
```

For some reason after the first user has connected, when I login from the second user, they seem to connect twice. Hence:

```
console.log(`User Connected: ${socket.id}`);
```

runs twice, making the server side console looking like:

> User Connected: pPNqnsAIJAUgDrpkAAAB
>
> User Connected: yZPm7IuY673r1hkUAAAD
>
> User Connected: yZPm7IuY673r1hkUAAAD

This is also resulting in the first user receiving the second user's messages twice because they seem to be connected twice.

I was making a simple socket.io chat server, but the second user's messages were being received twice by the first user. Upon further observation, I noticed that the second user connects to the server twice.